# Minecraft server disconnect/quit command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I once disconnected from a server using a command. I don't remember what the command was and i need that command to setup something for my server.

Does anyone know what's the command for disconnect/quit from server

Comment: You were almost certainly on a server that had some kind of command plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a specific command to disconnect yourself, but you could try kicking yourself from the server via:

```
kick <PlayerName> [reason]
```

Check out the [list of sever commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server_commands), maybe there's something more helpful there.

Comment: That would work for Operators and people with permission to kick. But in my case i want to allow members to /ragequit. Members can't kick. And i certainly do not want to give them the permission to

Comment: Is there a particular reason members cannot simply hit escape and quit, or just close minecraft? There doesn't seem to be a console command to disconnect that I can find.

Comment: @Murkantilism "doesn't seem to be a console command to disconnect" There aren'y any.

Answer (score 1):

There are no commands for disconnecting yourself. Try installing a server plugin which adds this capability.